# Convert time-series in columns to time-series in rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to prepare an **excel** spreadsheet in which I move timeseries data which is in rows into columns when each category (countries in this case) has a different number of data points. Apologies in advance if I am not describing this perfectly.

I'll make this clear with an example.This is a mock-up of what I currently have:

> ```
> Country         Year     Data
> Afghanistan     2000     10  
> Afghanistan     2004     12
> Afghanistan     2006     15
> Afghanistan     2010     30 
> Albania         2001     40
> Albania         2002     50
> Albania         2005     55
> Albania         2006     70
> Albania         2008     60
> Albania         2009     60
> Algeria         2000     23
> Algeria         2005     30
> Algeria         2006     40
> Algeria         2007     41
> Algeria         2008     39
> Algeria         2009     35
> Algeria         2010     40  
> ...
> ```

The data set is large and runs over a longer time period.

What I want the data set to look like is this:

> ```
> Country       2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006   2007     2008      2009    2010  
> Afghanistan:  10                              12              15                                30  
> Albania:              40       50                     55      70              60        60  
> Algeria:      23                                      30      40     41       39        35      40 
> ...
> ```

I can generate the structure that I want quite easily:

> ```
> Country      2000    2001     2002     2003    2004   2005    2006   2007     2008     2009    2010  
> Afghanistan  
> Albania    
> Algeria      
> ...
> ```

But I cannot work out how to populate the table.I think that I need to do an hlookup or vlookup, moving from columns to rows, and it needs to handle multiple criteria for matching - 'country' + 'year' (I tried concatinating, but that made too many data points: Afghanistan2000, Afghanistan2001, etc etc.).

Also pivot table doesn't seem to work because it sums the data, and copying "if(and(" statements won't work because its columns to rows.

I have been all over the internet and can't work out the tool for this. Nonetheless I am sure there is a simple solution, but i can't seem to work it out.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated as I get a lot of time series data in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions, however I actually managed to end up solving this using a pivot table. All that i had to do was create a pivot table. Set the columns to 'year', set the rows to 'country' and set the values to 'data'.

I then just had to set the 'field value setting' for data to 'max' and the table was populated. Took about 30 seconds in the end...

You can access the 'Field value setting' from the drop down menu on the 'data' field in the values box, within the Pivot Table Fields dialogue.

Thanks again for the answers I will definitely try the match, index formulas at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this **without any formulas** by building a query using [Get and Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) assuming you are on the latest version of Office on Windows.

Here is how to do it for the data you provided:

1. First, put the original data in a table (select any cell in the
   range > `ALT+N -> T`) and ensure the year column is sorted from smallest to largest
2. Next, make a query from the table (`ALT+O -> PT`)
3. In the Query Editor, go to the `Transform` tab and select `Pivot Column`
4. For the `Values Column` select `Data`
5. On the `Home` tab select `Close and Load`

This outputs the following table:

[image]

The best part about this is when the original source changes, you just need to re-run the query with `ALT+A -> R -> A` and it will populate new data.

Answer (score 0):

if the data is sorted then you could go with `INDEX:INDEX` and `MATCH` like for B2 (Sheet1 for the list and Sheet2 for formula asumed):
first set the range to look at via `MATCH`

```
MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)
MATCH(Sheet2!$A3,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)-1
```

this way you get the first and last row for the country. Now set the range to look at.

```
INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A3,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)-1)
```

The Output will look the same just for `$C:$C`.
To find the right row we use

```
MATCH(Sheet2!B$1,[Search range formula],0)
```

Put this in the full formula

```
INDEX([output range],[right row])
```

As this will error if no match is found also put an error part aound it

```
IFERROR([full formula],"")
```

all together it should look like this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(Sheet2!$A3,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)-1),MATCH(Sheet2!B$1,INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet2!$A3,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)-1),0)),"")
```

This can be auto filled to left and down as you need it. Just add a line after the last line in both lists like "zzz" or the last country will not output anything.

[image]

Done by Phone and may contain errors.

Answer (score 0):

Enter

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM($A$2:$A$18)=TRIM($E3))*(TRIM($B$2:$B$18)=TRIM(F$2))*$C$2:$C$18)
```

in `F3` and copy/drag it to fill the whole table (`F3:P5` in the example):

[image]

This formula places `0`, when there is no data,
so you can easily use `IF()` function
if you need to have empty cells instead.